# Selecting rows when some contain errors

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to select the Excel sheet's rows but certain rows contains errors. This is the selection code:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 2

Dim dRange As String
dRange = "1:1"

While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))

    dRange = dRange & "," & i & ":" & i

    i = i + 1

Wend

Range(dRange).EntireRow.Select
```

And this is a bugged row (CSV Exported):

```
08/03/2012;20120305;05/03/2012;20120305;Silba M.; -   ; 647,50 ; -   ;
-   ; 10.330,77 ;;Incasso affitto : URS
```

How can I solve my problem?

UPDATE:

I must search a value in column, for each row in the sheet. If i found that value i must export the row to another sheet. How can i do?

Comment: Please specify what the error you have, and check in debug window what is the `i` value, note that `Integer` type max value is 32767.

Comment: You want to skip the bugged rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example to copy the rows from sheet `Source` to sheet `Destination` which have the defined value in the defined column.

```
Sub RowsCopy()

    Dim objSrcSht As Worksheet
    Dim objDstSht As Worksheet
    Dim strSearchColumn As String
    Dim strSearchValue As String
    Dim lngDstRow As Long
    Dim lngSrcRow As Long

    Set objSrcSht = Sheets("Source") ' the sheet where to search
    strSearchColumn = "A" ' the column where to search
    strSearchValue = "sample" ' the value to be searched
    Set objDstSht = Sheets("Destination") ' the sheet where to copy the rows

    With objDstSht
        lngDstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    lngSrcRow = 2
    With objSrcSht
        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(lngSrcRow, 1))
            If .Cells(lngSrcRow, strSearchColumn) = strSearchValue Then
                objDstSht.Rows(lngDstRow).Value = .Rows(lngSrcRow).Value
                lngDstRow = lngDstRow + 1
            End If
            lngSrcRow = lngSrcRow + 1
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, now it select the rows without problems. Unfortunately, when i export the selected rows, i get this error: "That command cannot be user on multiple selection". The instruction is "Selection.Copy"

Comment: @Loris, I've edited the code to meet your requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately i must select rows coming from different part of the sheet and not continuosly

Comment: What you intend is not feasible that way, since `.Copy` method `... cannot be user on multiple selection`. Consider another algorithm. Add more details to your question. Maybe to copy row by row.. Note that usually you don't have to `.Select` cells before `.Copy` them.